# Scale element in X and Y by the same amount of pixels

Tags: css, css-transforms

I'd like to scale an element by the same absolute amount of pixels (not the same ratio) in the X and Y direction such that

```
newWidth = oldWidth + n
newHeight = oldHeight + n
```

where `n` is the number of pixels gained in size and `oldWidth` and `oldHeight` are unknown.

Is there a way to do this in pure CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the dimensions are unknown, you can't use CSS. In this case, only JavaScript can do that.

To do that in JavaScript, first grab the dimension of the element, and then add or subtract a value dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

You can use CSS variables like this:

## CSS

```
:root {
    --n: 100px
}
.sample {
    width: calc(300px + var(--n));
    height: calc(200px + var(--n));
}
```

## More dynamic but not recommend:

```
:root {
    --n: 100px;
    --width: 100px;
    --height: 100px;
}
.sample {
    width: calc(var(--width) + var(--n));
    height: calc(var(--height) + var(--n));
}
```

## AND...

```
:root {
    --n: 100px;
    --width: 100px;
    --height: 100px;
    --new-width: calc(var(--n) + var(--width));
    --new-height: calc(var(--n) + var(--height));
}
.sample {
    width: var(--new-width);
    height: var(--new-height);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the dimensions of the element are unknown, therefore this is not a solution. Sorry for not mentioning that in the post.

Comment: Also this doesn't actually scale the element as its contents stay the same size.

Comment: That would scale the element by a different amount of pixels in x and y if the width and height are unequal.

Answer (score 0):

```
transform: scaleY(calc(100% - calc(calc(8 * 100%) / 48))) scaleX(calc(100% - calc(calc(8 * 100%) / 152)));
```

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 152px;
  height: 48px;  
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.parent:hover .children {
  /* scale x,y 16px */
  transform: scaleY(calc(100% - calc(calc(16 * 100%) / 48))) scaleX(calc(100% - calc(calc(16 * 100%) / 152)));
}

.children {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #888;  
  transition: transform 200ms linear;
  /* scale x,y 1px */
  transform: scaleY(calc(100% - calc(calc(1 * 100%) / 48))) scaleX(calc(100% - calc(calc(1 * 100%) / 152)));
}

.text {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="text">Hover me</div>
</div>
```