# Scale element to pixel size

Tags: css, svg

I have an SVG element of dynamic size. I want to scale it and its contents **to** a particular pixel size (not *[by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61138101/scale-element-in-x-and-y-by-the-same-amount-of-pixels)* pixels) on demand.

This is invalid:

```
transform: scale(100px);
```

My knowledge of SVG is middling so maybe there's a better way, but setting the height/width of the SVG element after the contents are drawn simply causes its contents to runeth over, as they are "absolute" and not "relative" paths.

With JS you can just get the relative sizes:

```
const scaleX = targetWidth / svg.offsetWidth;
const scaleY = targetHeight / svg.offsetHeight;
svg.style.scale = `${scaleX}px ${scaleY}px`; //untested but you get the idea
```

My hope is there is a sort of "scaleTo" somewhere in CSS3 I'm unaware of, or neat trick to accomplish this. An authoritative "no" is an acceptable answer.

Comment: could you clarify the problem - if you simply want to fit a 'big' svg  into a smaller container, setting it's css width to 100% of it's parent container's (specified) width will work. If you need to retrieve pixel values for some computation from an SVG image after scaling in an element's smaller size, you will need to do some arithmetic. If it's simply a method of specifying SVG 'pixels' that allow you to set it's size to an exact element size, the `viewbox` attrribute can do that fairly simply.

Comment: @DavePritlove setting css height/width smaller causes the inner svg elements (paths) to be clipped. Using transform:scale() doesn't work, because I don't know the px value of the initial state, so I can't know what ratio to scale by with CSS. I haven't tried anything with `viewbox`. I'm trying to resize from dynamic to absolute height/width

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the html for the svg, you can remove the svg element's width and height attributes and replace them with a `viewBox` attribute of the with the x/y positions set to 0, and the width/height pair set to the values you deleted:

```
<svg width="300" height="200">
<!-- change to: -->
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 200">
```

You can then place the svg element inside a sized div and set the css width and height of the svg to 100%:

```
    .svgContainer svg {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
```

See working snippet to compare effects, I've squeezed the same svg into a smaller div, with and without the `viewBox` set.

**Note** for a dynamic resize, the div container has to resize dynamically, the `viewBox` version of the svg set to 100% width and height of the container will take care of itself. If the container Div had been sized by % instead of pixels, it will grow and shrink with the viewport of the browser.

If you can't access the html markup, you could achieve the same by retrieving the `width` and `height` attributes of the svg using javascript and set a new attribute for the `viewBox`.

More about `viewBox`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox

```css
.svgContainer {
  width: 100px;
}

.svgContainer svg {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<p> 300x200 svg rendered outside of a container:</p>
<svg width="300px" height="200px">
<rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" stroke="blue"/>
<rect x="100" y="50" width="100" height="50" fill="yellow"/>
<rect x="30" y="20" width="20" height="35" fill="blue"/>
</svg>

<p> same 300x200 svg rendered inside sized div:</p>
<div class="svgContainer">
<svg width="300px" height="200px">
<rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" stroke="blue"/>
<rect x="100" y="50" width="100" height="50" fill="yellow"/>
<rect x="30" y="20" width="20" height="35" fill="blue"/>
</svg>
</div>

<p>svg modified to use viewbox attribute values, inside sized div</p>
<div class="svgContainer">
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 200">
<rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" stroke="blue"/>
<rect x="100" y="50" width="100" height="50" fill="yellow"/>
<rect x="30" y="20" width="20" height="35" fill="blue"/>
</svg>
</div>
```